# PHP issue with ordering results

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code to get the images and show them by order

```
$qry2 = "SELECT * FROM bx_photos_main 
         WHERE Categories='Articles' 
         ORDER BY Title ASC";

$qryr2 = mysql_query($qry2) or die("Error selecting: ".mysql_error());

while($qryrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($qryr2)) {
    $photo_book_id = $qryrow2['ID'];

    $a = array ('ID' => $aAuthor['ID'], 'Avatar' => $photo_book_id);

    $aMedia_book_icon = BxDolService::call('photos', 'get_image', array($a, 'file'), 'Search');

    $aMedia_book_iconUrl = $aMedia_book_icon['file'];

    //if($media_book_id == $photo_book_id) {        
          $sRet .='<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="'.$aMedia_book_iconUrl.'" title=""><img src="'.$aMedia_book_iconUrl.'"></a>';
    // }
}
```

Everything works fine, but as soon as I put a check of the results, like the one commented above `if($media_book_id == $photo_book_id) {` I loose the order completely.

Why? What's wrong? Why do I loose the order of the results when I use a PHP statement? How do I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what's being returned and what the desired return is so that we can see the difference?

Comment: I'll bet you a beer the order of the data is not changed by this check. What *might* happen is that some records aren't added any more

Comment: Where do you define $media_book_id?
@Pekka I thought finish people only drank vodka? (assuming that you're finish by your name).

Comment: $media_book_id is the result of another while loop that contains the above code

Comment: @Runar I'm half Finnish, but the German half is stronger! :) Although I *mostly* drink  red wine to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that your if statement removes some of your rows because of the statement itself. When those two variables are not equal you won't get the information in the current row added to the `$sRet` variable.

```
$sRet .='<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="'.$aMedia_book_iconUrl.'" title="">
<img src="'.$aMedia_book_iconUrl.'"></a>';
```

What you can do is add an `else` to your if statement to see when they aren't equal. Your if statement would then be something like this:

```
if($media_book_id == $photo_book_id) {        
    $sRet .='<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="'.$aMedia_book_iconUrl.'" title="">
             <img src="'.$aMedia_book_iconUrl.'"></a>';
} else {
    echo "Error - Media_book_id: $media_book_id. Photo_book_id: $photo_book_id";
}
```